# Import free text files

Tags: import, sas, nlp

I have been asked to do NLP on a folder of free text documents in SAS. Normally I do this in Python or R and I am not sure how to import he txt files into SAS because there is no structure.

I have thought about using proc import but don't know what I would use as a delimiter. How can one import free text files with no structure into SAS? I supposed once I got in I could use things '%like%' sort of items to pull out what they want.

Comment: Suggest you show a few rows of a sample file.  Also how you would want it stored in SAS.

Comment: This is too broad (and missing details) to answer right now.  You do it any number of ways depending on what you're using.  Are you using Text Miner?  (That's the product I'd expect you to use for this sort of thing.)  The broad answer is that you INPUT to a text string, but it really depends.  Do some research, this is pretty well covered already.

Comment: I can't show a sample file but they are all over the place.  I guess Input would work. I am not using Text Miner. I wish I was using Text Miner but I have been told I am not using Text Miner.

Comment: You need to be able to show a sample file - it doesn't have to be actual data or anything secret, but something that looks more or less like what you're trying to process.  Otherwise how are we supposed to help?

Comment: What Analytics are you trying to do? In BASE you basically are doing to have to code all your algorithms so I'd strongly suggest getting EMiner or calling R from IML if required.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend against this. Use the right tool for the right job, in this case it's not SAS.

Ok, that being said some basics you could do:
Import text files and create n grams. Ideally, 1,2 &3 words.

Use PROC FREQ to summarize n-grams.

Find a parts of speech corpus and merge than with the 1 gram to remove useless words.

Calculate length of words and length of sentence to create a document complexity score.

Those are all doable in Base.